# Python код в браузере

Tags: python, flask, браузер

Есть ли такая возможность, чтобы посмотреть исходный код на python через браузер? По примеру того, как мы можем посмотреть html разметку сайта. (web-приложение написано на Flask)

Comment: нет............

Comment: Ну, если вы добавите в ваш код, который обрабатывается flask, такую возможность - отдавать текст файла с кодом python, то да

Comment: для этого существует реверсная инженерия.для мазахистов

Comment: Спасибо , я вас понял)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя, но если очень хочется, то можно написать обработчик на том же фласке, который будет отправлять файл с кодом по запросу.

```
@app.route('/code/<path:filename>')
import __main__

def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __main__.__file__ )),
        filename, as_attachment=True)
```

PS. Не делайте так

Используйте панельку с с отладчиком, если у Вас возникают проблемы с кодом https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, мне как раз так нужно было!

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению код бекэнда увидеть нельзя. Так как он просто не передается клиенту. Клиенту передается только, то что хочет передать сервер. И не важно python это или php.

Comment: Кому к сожалению, кому к счастью)